# Face Detection Using Own Custom Model From The Scratch - Need Guidance

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

Goal : I want to build a model which can detect "number of faces" present in a picture.
What I have : 
24533 Images to train, One CSV file which includes, 
7 column - [Image_ID, width, height, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]

I want to build my own model by fitting this data to Keras Dense layer so that while passing any image or bunch of image it could give me a result with Image_ID & number of faces present in photo.

I have gone through a lot of documents including how to use YOLO, ImageAI, HAAR cascade XML Library but in every case, it is addressed how to use these libraries without building own model.

Please guide me on how to use the information I already have to build my own model without using the existing one.